# I am new to Groovy, I am running below Groovy Script. But here my objects are getting overridden

Tags: groovy

Here I need to do the count on Index of original and based on this index it will fetch the data in response field. I am not sure why my output is getting overwritten and not working as expected. Am I missing something. I am running below Groovy Script. I am not sure why my output is getting overwritten

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.* 
import java.nio.charset.*

response_api = """
{
  "original" : [ {
    "inp1" : 18,
    "id" : 184000,
    "rownum" : 123
  }, {
    "inp1" : 18,
    "id" : 184001,
    "rownum" : 121
  },
  {
    "inp1" : 19,
    "id" : 184002,
    "rownum" : 124
  } ]
,
  "response" : [ {
    "Record" : "Record 2",
    "Description" : "Internal Server Error."
  }, {
    "Record" : "Record 3",
    "Description" : "Processing failed due to record 2"
  } ]
}
"""

class Result{
    Success[] SuccessRecords
    Failed[] FailedRecords
    public Result( Success[] SuccessRecords, Failed[] FailedRecords){
        this.SuccessRecords = SuccessRecords
        this.FailedRecords = FailedRecords
    }
}

class Success{
    int rownum
    int inp1
    String Status
    public Success(int rownum, int inp1,String Status){
        this.rownum = rownum
        this.inp1 = inp1
        this.Status = Status
    }
}

class Failed{
    int rownum
    int inp1
    String Status
    String ErrorDescription
    public Failed(int rownum, int inp1,String Status,String ErrorDescription){
        this.rownum = rownum
        this.inp1 = inp1
        this.Status = Status
        this.ErrorDescription = ErrorDescription
    }
}
def Failed[] fail
def Success[] successful
def api_response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response_api)
int j = api_response.original.size()
 for (int i=0;i<j;i++){
                index =  i+1
                def rec = 'Record ' + index
                if (rec in api_response.response.Record){
                   
                      Failed failed = new Failed(api_response.original.rownum[i],api_response.original.inp1[i],"Failed",api_response.response.Description[i])
                      fail = [failed]
                      
                }
                
                else {
                   Success success = new Success(api_response.original.rownum[i],api_response.original.inp1[i],"Success")
                   successful = [success]
                }
             
 }
            
def Result myJson = new Result(successful,fail)
def finalJson = new JsonBuilder(myJson)
println finalJson.toPrettyString()
```

output of the Script:

```
{
    "failedRecords": [
        {
            "errorDescription": null,
            "status": "Failed",
            "rownum": 124,
            "inp1": 19
        }
    ],
    "successRecords": [
        {
            "status": "Success",
            "rownum": 123,
            "inp1": 18
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "failedRecords": [
        {
            "rownum": 121,
            "inp1": 18,
            "status": "Failed",
            "errorDescription":"Internal Server Error."
        },
        {
            "rownum": 124,
            "inp1": 19,
            "status": "Failed",
            "errorDescription": "Processing failed due to record 2"
        }
    ],
    "successRecords": [
        {
           "rownum": 123,
            "inp1": 18,
            "status": "Success"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like `fail += failed` instead of `fail = [failed]`. `fail = [failed]` is replacing the list, not appending to it. The same is true for `success`.

Try this...

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.* 
import java.nio.charset.*

response_api = """
{
  "original" : [ {
    "inp1" : 18,
    "id" : 184000,
    "rownum" : 123
  }, {
    "inp1" : 18,
    "id" : 184001,
    "rownum" : 121
  },
  {
    "inp1" : 19,
    "id" : 184002,
    "rownum" : 124
  } ]
,
  "response" : [ {
    "Record" : "Record 2",
    "Description" : "Internal Server Error."
  }, {
    "Record" : "Record 3",
    "Description" : "Processing failed due to record 2"
  } ]
}
"""

class Result{
    Success[] SuccessRecords
    Failed[] FailedRecords
    public Result( Success[] SuccessRecords, Failed[] FailedRecords){
        this.SuccessRecords = SuccessRecords
        this.FailedRecords = FailedRecords
    }
}

class Success{
    int rownum
    int inp1
    String Status
    public Success(int rownum, int inp1,String Status){
        this.rownum = rownum
        this.inp1 = inp1
        this.Status = Status
    }
}

class Failed{
    int rownum
    int inp1
    String Status
    String ErrorDescription
    public Failed(int rownum, int inp1,String Status,String ErrorDescription){
        this.rownum = rownum
        this.inp1 = inp1
        this.Status = Status
        this.ErrorDescription = ErrorDescription
    }
}
Failed[] fail = []
Success[] successful = []
def api_response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response_api)
int j = api_response.original.size()
 for (int i=0;i<j;i++){
                index =  i+1
                def rec = 'Record ' + index
                if (rec in api_response.response.Record){
                   
                      Failed failed = new Failed(api_response.original.rownum[i],api_response.original.inp1[i],"Failed",api_response.response.find {it.Record == rec}.Description)
                      fail += failed
                      
                }
                
                else {
                   Success success = new Success(api_response.original.rownum[i],api_response.original.inp1[i],"Success")
                   successful += success
                }
             
 }
            
def Result myJson = new Result(successful,fail)
def finalJson = new JsonBuilder(myJson)
println finalJson.toPrettyString()
```

Or this...

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.* 
import java.nio.charset.*

response_api = """
{
  "original" : [ {
    "inp1" : 18,
    "id" : 184000,
    "rownum" : 123
  }, {
    "inp1" : 18,
    "id" : 184001,
    "rownum" : 121
  },
  {
    "inp1" : 19,
    "id" : 184002,
    "rownum" : 124
  } ]
,
  "response" : [ {
    "Record" : "Record 2",
    "Description" : "Internal Server Error."
  }, {
    "Record" : "Record 3",
    "Description" : "Processing failed due to record 2"
  } ]
}
"""

class Result{
    Success[] SuccessRecords
    Failed[] FailedRecords
    public Result( Success[] SuccessRecords, Failed[] FailedRecords){
        this.SuccessRecords = SuccessRecords
        this.FailedRecords = FailedRecords
    }
}

class Success{
    int rownum
    int inp1
    String Status
    public Success(int rownum, int inp1,String Status){
        this.rownum = rownum
        this.inp1 = inp1
        this.Status = Status
    }
}

class Failed{
    int rownum
    int inp1
    String Status
    String ErrorDescription
    public Failed(int rownum, int inp1,String Status,String ErrorDescription){
        this.rownum = rownum
        this.inp1 = inp1
        this.Status = Status
        this.ErrorDescription = ErrorDescription
    }
}
Failed[] fail = []
Success[] successful = []
def api_response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response_api)
int j = api_response.original.size()
 for (int i=0;i<j;i++){
                index =  i+1
                def rec = 'Record ' + index
                def matchingRecord = api_response.response.find {
                    it.Record == rec
                }
                if (matchingRecord){
                   
                      fail += new Failed(api_response.original.rownum[i],api_response.original.inp1[i],"Failed",matchingRecord.Description)
                      
                }
                
                else {
                   successful += new Success(api_response.original.rownum[i],api_response.original.inp1[i],"Success")
                }
             
 }
            
def Result myJson = new Result(successful,fail)
def finalJson = new JsonBuilder(myJson)
println finalJson.toPrettyString()
```

Comment: Hi @Jeff Scott Brown, Thank you so much for your help.